# Matching Unicode control characters except for three with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, unicode, pcre, control-characters

I would need to get a Regular Expression, which matches all Unicode control characters except for carriage return (0x0d), line feed (0x0a) and tabulator (0x09). Currently, my Regular Expression looks like this:

```
/\p{C}/u
```

I just need to define these three exceptions now.

Comment: Is this for PHP? To give you the best answer we need to know which regex flavor you're using. Darth Eru's answer will work in PHP, but other flavors would require a different approach.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which PHP uses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use a negative lookahead here, combined with character classes.

```
/(?![\x{000d}\x{000a}\x{0009}])\p{C}/u
```

What this does is use a negative lookahead to assert that the character is not one of those specified in the character class.  Then it traverses the character again to match it with any control character.

I used the perl syntax for specifying single unicode points.

More discussion on lookarounds [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

(Note that this has not been tested, but I think the concept is correct.)

Comment: It's a real shame that .NET `Regex` doesn't just have a IsControlCharacter unicode named block to match `System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.Control`.  It would be great if I could just use that instead of manually specifying all the control characters.